# Cloud Firestore Data Structure

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an application that uses cloud firestore to store data about "events" in our lab on several assets.  We collected data for a few months and we are averaging about 2000 events per asset per month.  Each event captures a few pieces of meta data that the user can query.

I imported all the data into firestore with a very simple layout at first.

> Events (Collection of event data)
>       -> EventData (documents which contains a few fields for metadata)

From my understanding, even if the collection of events becomes quite large, for billing and speed of queries this won't be a problem (assuming I do some sort of pagination on the query results).  The composite indexes are also very manageable with this structure.

The problem I see, is if someone goes and looks at the firestore console and brings that collection up, our read requests go through the roof.  It seems that does a full read on the entire collection...which of course will kill us on billing as time goes on.  I don't see this as a problem forever as eventually we should get to the point where everything is stable and won't need to go into the console very often, but what if someone does when we have a million or more records.

My next thought was to structure the database like this:

> Events -> Assets -> {Asset_Name } -> {year_month} -> {Collection of
>   Document with field meta-data}

This certainly solves the issue of the ever growing collection of documents.  The number of assets that we have is fixed, and the number of events is (effectively) capped to a maximum amount per month as well.  The problem with this setup, however, is managing composite indexes.  There are about 5 indexes needed for my original setup.  I think this alternative setup means I would need to setup the same 5 indexes for each each collection of documents for every asset every month.

I thought maybe there could be a way to have a cloud function manage it for me (it doesn't appear there is an API for this).  I think the number of indexes per project is also capped.

So, in the end, I am looking for recommendations on how to structure this database to limit reads if using the console, as well as keeping the indexes manageable.  I am pretty new to NoSQL and perhaps I am just completely off.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you keep your structure as is if that's what's working for you. You should not need to optimize for reducing console reads. Console reads do count towards your usage but the console does not load the entire collection when you open the console.

The console loads just enough documents to let you scroll a bit and then it loads more documents if you scroll down. It will only load the entire collection if you scroll through the entire collection.